# SinonJS fake timer does not work with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit, sinon

I am running the following code with SinonJS and QUnit:

```
var clock = this.sandbox.useFakeTimers();
var el = jQuery("<div></div>");
el.appendTo(document.body);

el.animate({ height: "200px", width: "200px" });
clock.tick(1000);

equals("200px", el.css("height"));
equals("200px", el.css("width"));
```

But the test fails, looks like jQuery is using the real clock and not the fake one.

I am using Chrome 12.0.742.122.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: A jsfiddle/jsbin example would help figuring this out.

Comment: I ended up submiting an issue to the SinonJS github project: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/30 
Here's a jsfiddle with the problem and an ugly workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/VCMAc/

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery is using window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame or window.mozRequestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.
>
> If you set window.mozRequestAnimationFrame to false before loading jQuery, it will use setTimeout and SinonJS will work properly.